# Some approaches to distribute an iPhone application to run in a specific location

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution, software-distribution

My boss wants to distribute the application for a specific client, whose number of employees is around 500. The application uses webservices and the UDID of the device to restrict the other users from accessing the software. We are not a big company that can register for the enterprise program, and especially my boss does not want other users to download the software because it may lead to overload to the server, even though we use the udid to restrict the user but the first webservice request is still needed to verify if the iPhone/iPod is granted to use the system.

Putting the software into the appstore with free price leads to many unwanted things: writing comments to blame the software that he can not use it (in fact, other users do not suppose to use it, only the client of the company is the one that has the right to use the software) or even we can think of the software be confidential and should not be exposed to other users.

Putting the software into the appstore with the maximum price is not a good approach because then our client has to pay money to download the program. It's not necessary.

Distributing the software in the ad-hoc mode requires us to reinstall the software every time the provisioning profile is expired, even worse, the installation limit is only 100 devices.

So, what are the approaches to distribute this kind of software? Any thoughts on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is our solution and it works on the appstore:
- Distribute your app as usual on the appstore
- In your app, limit it to a certain devices by letting it query a service on your own managed server.
- Authentication is necessary if you want to differentiate between users.

Comment: Hi sfa, I am in a somewhat similar situation as you are. It sounds like you put the app in the app store with a free price, and then had the app query a service on your own server. But what about the problems you outlined in your question, you did not have those problems? Like people writing comments that put blame on the software because he cannot use it. Or the load on your server? Or maybe I misunderstood your approach? I appreciate your reply. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, we put the app in the Store for free, with a description saying that it is available only for a specific range of customers, they did write bad comments, but we don't care, as we are paid by the direct customers that we had contract with. We talked directly to customers about our solution and showed them the demos, they can install the app by follow our instruction, downloading the app from the store, and configure with the right parameters to make the app work. Though the server address is not visible to anyone. That's how we did to avoid unnecessary requests from unwanted users.

Comment: However, I suggest that you review the AppStore review guidelines, they may change their policy to this type of app to be accepted on the AppStore. So you must be careful, risk is still on your part.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick answer. I did not realize that you had already answered my question, I thought I would receive a notification or something. Yes Apple might have changed their guidelines, I'm going to have to find some way, maybe to make an app useable by all people, and have like a special area of the app for people with special access. Thankyou for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Suck it up and pay for the [enterprise developer program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/).  Its only $299/year. Or look into jailbreaking every employee's device and installing your app through alternate means.

Comment: Hi coney, from the website, it says: "You must be a company or organization with 500 or more employees and a DUNS number to apply." In fact, we are not that big company, we are just a small one but we provide the services to multiple clients. We are ready to pay $299 but the program is not suitable for us.

Comment: @Hoang Pham: In this case, you should be able to explain that the client of this application is indeed large enough, and maybe even have them pay the fee and sign up.  You could still be a member or administrator of their enterprise team and be able to build and distribute their application.  Getting a DUNS number is trivial.  At my day job, we're a four-person company and we have one, so your client should be able to get one themselves (or already have one).

Comment: hi Brad, thank you for your response, but what happen if one of the client companies does not have enough 500 employee? that client in this case does not qualify for the program anymore.